# MacOS Catalina - node express app - http localhost server failing

Tags: node.js, express, http, macos-catalina

I recently upgdated my MacOS to Catalina. When trying start up my local Node Epress app using:

`npm start`

I get this error:

```
xxxxx:app xxxx$ npm start

> xxxx@0.0.1 start /Users/xxxxx/Documents/GitHub/xxxxxx/app
> node ./bin/www

/Users/xxxxx/Documents/GitHub/xxxxxx/app/bin/www:76
      throw error;
      ^

Error: listen EPROTOTYPE: protocol wrong type for socket 0.0.0.0:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1281:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1346:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1434:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/GitHub/xxxxxxx/app/bin/www:28:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'EPROTOTYPE',
  errno: 'EPROTOTYPE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3000
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! xxxxxx@0.0.1 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the xxxxxx@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xxxxxx/.npm/_logs/2020-03-27T02_53_45_621Z-debug.log
```

**Before updating MacOS to Catalina** everything worked fine. `./bin/www` looks like as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried to generate a brand new node express app via generator - doesnt work either.

**If I restart my Mac, server works if I start it up in first 30 sec!**

After that time seems like the port is blocked or something?

Seems like it must be some kind of firewall of something?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use different http server packages - completely same errors! - Error: listen EPROTOTYPE: protocol wrong type for socket 0.0.0.0:8080

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

https://www.npmjs.com/package/server

The problem has to be in MacOS Catalina!

---

**UPDATE:**

I discovered that the problem must be firewall or something installed on my MAC.

When I disconnect my laptop from WIFI, everything works as expected.

Comment: That's odd, is `app` a regular koa/express instance? If you don't think anything else has changed maybe try upgrade node to a more recent build?

Comment: it is. I tried to update node with no avail. I also tried to generate a brand new express app from scratch....same error when trying to start the server. I got a suspition it has to be something with MacOS and some network security stuff?

Comment: you're hitting http:// not https:// in browser right?

Comment: Does app work fine if you don't put extra error handler on server's listen but rather something like `process.on('uncaughtException', (e) => {...`

Comment: unfortunately didnt help :( I use neither http nor https as I am not able to start up the local server at all :(